# create lambda for pandas read_excel

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

In PyCharm, I'm trying to create a date parser lambda to pass in to `pandas.read_excel` but it throws a TypeError: `strptime() argument 1 must be string, not datetime.datetime`:

```py
parser = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%d-%m-%y")
read_file = pd.read_excel(
    file_path, skiprows=2, parse_dates=[10, 13], date_parser=parser
)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that `parse_dates` and `date_parser`, which is optional, are conflicting.

One workaround is to use `converters` instead, as per Pandas [read_excel documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html), like this:

```py
from datetime import datetime

import pandas as pd

parser = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%d-%m-%y")

df = pd.read_excel("path_to_file", skiprows=2, converters={10: parser, 13: parser})
```